# Problems creating a NativeScript plugin that uses Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, plugins, nativescript

I have followed the NativeScript documentation on adding Objective-C code to a NS project although I am struggling to call the Objective-C code in my iOS project. I am only trying to implement `appPlugin.h` and `appPlugin.m` files into my project.

My folder structure for the Objective-C files are as follows:

- Project/app/App_Resources/iOS/src/...

I have also tried creating a NativeScript plugin that gets added to the dependencies in the projects `package.json`.

Are there any additional files that need to be added to make the Objective-C code compatible with the NS project. The documentation simply says run "If you run 'tns prepare ios' you will see that the files are now part of the project."

Link to the documentation I have been following:

- https://www.nativescript.org/blog/adding-objective-c-code-to-a-nativescript-app
- https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Files are added to the TNSNativeSource folder (Check in Xcode) and are available to use like any JS object.